# $(window).load in JQUERY is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complicated application where the html and styles are rendered by a framework. I need to get things such as heights, offsets, scrollTop positions, etc from many elements when the page loads. I know

```
$( document ).ready
```

Fires before styles are applied to elements hence why I am using window.load instead. The problem is it I can't get it to fire? I have create a fiddle with the new and old way to fire window load, but its not working. In my application I am using jquery 1.11.1, the fiddle uses 1.9.1.

How I am actually calling my code in my application:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="javascript" source="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"/>
</head>
<body>
<H1>
  TITLE
</H1>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
   alert("Window Loaded 1 ");
 });

 $(window).on('load', function() {
   alert("Window Loaded 2 ");
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jzLkrve/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event listener shortcut is deprecated

Use `$(window).on('load', function` instead. Also keep it outside of `$(document).ready()` or `window.onload`

The fiddle automatically puts your code inside `onload` callback which is why it is not working in your demo. If you change the "Load Type" in fiddle to a "no wrap" the demo works fine

**Update based on new html added to question.** Your script tag is invalid

Change

```
<script type="javascript" source="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"/>
```

To

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
       <!-- ^ src not source                               ^^ needs closing tag
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. In my actual code the code is being called like this. It is not wrapped in $(document).ready() and it is still not being fired

Comment: Can't use self closing <script> tag and there is no `source` it is `src`. Fixing script tag your code works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/1eXPu0y26FeKGUgX0sYG?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

3 things goes wrong here

- Can't use self-closing `<script />` tag
- It should be `src`, not `source`
- The `type` is `type="text/javascript"`, not `type="javascript"`, do note:

  > HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the `type` attribute rather than
  >   provide a redundant MIME type.

  Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

Stack snippet

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<H1>
  TITLE
</H1>

<script>

 $(window).load(function() {
   alert("Window Loaded 1 ");
 });

 $(window).on('load', function() {
   alert("Window Loaded 2 ");
 });
</script>
```